# How to assign a sub-class instance to an Enum item implementing the same interface?

Tags: java

```
interface A {}
class B implements A{}
enum C implements A {
  ITEM_A,
  ITEM_B,
  // Can I do something like `ITEM_C = new B()`?
}
```

I can probably make the enum hold a reference to a `A` instance, instead of `implements` it, but that's not ideal.

Comment: You can't do it in the way you describe, but you can pass an instance of `B` to your enum declaration.  All of that to say... *why* do you want to do this again?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: An enum can't extend another class (because it already extends `Enum`). But it sounds like you may have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain what you're really after.

Comment: I use A as labels. But I have a few special cases (B) with some logic. I was using a class to enclose all possible A values, including B. That worked well. I was trying to swap it with an enum, which seems to be better for known, finite set of elements, with switch warning etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This can't be done as C and B are entirely different from each other and not at all related

Only a parent class reference can hold a child class object. B &C doesn't have that relationship. So, it's not possible.

Comment: Right! Thanks. Somehow I had the hallucination that C is A, while C is-a A.